# Maya Error - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maya.cmds'

Tags: python-3.x, scripting, maya, maya-api

I am using ubuntu 18.04, python 3.6.

I installed maya using :

```
pip install maya
```

then tried to run this :

```
import maya.cmds
```

then i got the module not found error.

Then i installed :

```
pip install maya-cmds-help
```

But again same error is showing.
How can i get rid of this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you executing this from within Maya? If so, the bundled Python interpreter should have automatically done whatever needs doing to give you access to maya.cmds.

Comment: No, im executing the script outside maya. Is it possible ? Like im trying to create a script for searching some file types.

Comment: Maya command can only used from within maya or from mayapy in commandline. And maya still uses Python 2.7.

Comment: Why do you specifically need maya's api to search for file types? Isn't `os` enough?

Comment: What i really need is a script for automatically loading missing files in the reference editor and printing out the missing files which is shown in and file path editor. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The module you install https://pypi.org/project/maya/ has nothing to do with the Autodesk Maya.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to query and edit Maya files without opening an actual Maya session, use [mayapy](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2022/ENU/Maya-Scripting/files/GUID-D64ACA64-2566-42B3-BE0F-BCE843A1702F-htm.html). It's an external Python interpreter that allows you to access maya.cmds